# Error with Node of Tree Class, perhaps because of private Node members

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, private, members

So I've been testing a tree node class and have encountered some errors. I think it's because I'm using private Node members and using accessor functions to access them. Using the del function, I attempted to print and delete the test tree while traversing in PostOrder, but there is no output, except for the "root".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef TREENODE_H
#define TREENODE_H
template <class T>
class TreeNode
{
private:
    typedef TreeNode<T>* nodePtr;
    T data;
    nodePtr lst;
    nodePtr rst;
public:
    TreeNode()
    {
        lst = NULL;
        rst = NULL;
    };
    TreeNode(T d)
    {
        data = d;
        lst = NULL;
        rst = NULL;
    };
    TreeNode(const TreeNode<T>* other)
    {
        data = other.data;
        lst = other.lst;
        rst = other.rst;
    };

    void setData(T d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    void setLeft(nodePtr l)
    {
        lst = l;
    }

    void setRight(nodePtr r)
    {
        rst = r;
    }

    nodePtr getLeft()
    {
        return lst;
    }

    nodePtr getRight()
    {
        return rst;
    }

    ~TreeNode()
    {
        cout << "gone: " << data;
    }
};
#endif
```

And

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TreeNode.cpp"

using namespace std;



void recInsert(string a, TreeNode<string>* current)
{
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current = new TreeNode < string > ;
        current->setData(a);
        current->setLeft(NULL);
        current->setRight(NULL);
    }
    else if (a <= current->getData())
        recInsert(a, current->getLeft());
    else recInsert(a, current->getRight());
};

void del(TreeNode < string > *current)
{
    if (current != NULL)
    {
        del(current->getLeft());
        del(current->getRight());
        cout << current->getData();
        delete current;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TreeNode<string>* a;
    a = new TreeNode <string>;
    a->setData("hi");
    recInsert("ho", a);
    recInsert("bo", a);
    recInsert("ao", a);
    recInsert("lo", a);
    del(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you are trying to add a left or right child node your `recInsert` function receives a pointer to a node instead of a pointer to a pointer or reference to a pointer. So you are changing the function parameter instead of a child node. Here is a quick fix:

```
void recInsert(string a, TreeNode<string>*& current) {
    // The same code
}
```

And here is a bit of background reading:
[Pointer to Pointer and Reference to Pointer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer)